# How do I set window size

Tags: window

When I start emacs, I would like to have it set up so that there is a scratch buffer on top and a terminal on the bottom. I would like the terminal to be 15 lines tall. So far I have

```
(defun startup-layout ()
  (interactive)
  (delete-other-windows)
  (split-window-vertically)
  (next-multiframe-window)
  (enlarge-window ( - 15 window-body-height))
  (term "/bin/bash")
  (previous-multiframe-window)
  )
(startup-layout)
```

How can I set the window size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window-body-height` is function not variable. so the corrected code would be

```
(defun startup-layout ()
  (interactive)
  (delete-other-windows)
  (split-window-vertically)
  (next-multiframe-window)
  (enlarge-window ( - 15 (window-body-height)))
  (term "/bin/bash")
  (previous-multiframe-window)
  )
(startup-layout)
```

and adjust the number 15 according to your screen size/resolution.